# Data manipulation for user uploaded data - Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe that I manipulated to look at the overall percent of fails per number of observations and also the percentage for the last 30 days. There may be a more eloquent way to do this, but this is what I came up with and it yields the final result I want.

```
a$FAIL<-ifelse(a$OPERATION_STATUS %in% "FAIL", 1, 0)
cc<-as.data.frame((table(a$CRIT_CODE))) #Dataframe with frequency  of each crit code
cf<-aggregate(FAIL~CRIT_CODE,a,sum) #Total number of fails based  on crit codes
(cc<-cbind(cc[,],cf[,2]))
names(cc)<-c("CRIT_CODE", "Freq", "FAIL") #Change column names
(cc<-transform(cc, Percent=FAIL/Freq*100))

last30<-a[which(a$DATE>=(Sys.Date()-30)),]
last<-as.data.frame((table(last30$CRIT_CODE))) #Dataframe with frequency of each crit code
lastfails<-aggregate(FAIL~CRIT_CODE,last30,sum) #Total number of fails based on crit codes
(last<-cbind(last[,],lastfails[,2]))
names(last)<-c("CRIT_CODE", "Freq", "FAIL") #Change column names
(last<-transform(last, Percent=FAIL/Freq*100))

rates<-merge(critcode[,c(1,4)], last[,c(1,4)], by="CRIT_CODE")
rates$Percent.x<-round(rates$Percent.x, 2)
rates$Percent.y<-round(rates$Percent.y, 2)
library(gridExtra)
grid.table(rates, cols=c("Area", "Overall Percent", "30 Day Percent"))
```

I want to incorporate this into a Shiny app where the user can upload their own dataset (with the same headings), so the 30 day percentage can be continually updated. I am new to Shiny and am having a hard time figuring out how to implement this code. While looking through Shiny tutorials and other StackOverflow questions, it seems a lot of people do multiple reactive statements to manipulate data.  I feel like there must be a better way because this would seem to require a lot of reactive statements for one table. Is there a better recommendation for how to incorporate this into Shiny?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using data.table package the following works:

```
setDT(audit)
audit[,group_i := DATE >=Sys.Date()-30]
rates <- audit[, .(
    'Overall Percent' = round(sum(OPERATION_STATUS == 'FAIL') / .N * 100, 2),
    '30 Day Percent' = round(sum(OPERATION_STATUS[group_i] == 'FAIL') / sum(group_i) * 100, 2)
    ),
    keyby = .(Area = CRIT_CODE)]
```